# A Super Battery Saver App for windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, battery

Is there a windows 10 app or procedure that can allow me to only have the wifi and chrome open along with the most basic keyboard functions so that I can maximize my battery usage? I don't want any background app, process, anti-virus, countdowns/checks/updates, or even windows functions like taskbar or such, etc. using energy.

I am reading novels on a website and not using anything else on my laptop.

Something like the basic DOS but just chrome, wifi, and keyboard.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome rukuto! Interesting question you pose. When you wrote "only have the wifi and chrome open" are you referring to Google's Chrome web browser?  Your second paragraph encourages me think this is the case.

Comment: Chrome might not be the best choice of browser. It often sucks up a lot of CPU on my computer.

Comment: You may want to try something else than Windows in this case. ChromeOS is specifically built for that purpose. Windows inherently has lots of background things running up.